# Why does a promise returned from a function resolve to value returned from .then inside that function

Tags: javascript, promise

I created a function that returns a promise.

```
function fetch1 () {
 return new Promise((res, rej) => {
  res("A");
 });
}
```

I call this function inside a function api1 and return the promise returned from fetch1.

```
function api1 () {
 return fetch1().then(v =>{
  console.log("Api1", v);
  return "B"
 );
}
```

As you can see I am returning the same value which is returned from fetch1. I am not creating any new Promise. But when I call this I get following output.

```
api1().then(v => console.log("Api2 call", v));

Api1 A
Api2 call B
```

My expected output should be

```
Api1 A
Api2 call A
```

As you can see from this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). That promise then are chained. A promise returned from first then is resolved in next then. But I am not returning any promise from then inside api1 function.

I can go around it. But why it occurs.

Comment: function api1 () {
 return fetch1().then(v =>{
  console.log("Api1", v);
  return "B" //<=== DUE TO THIS LINE
 );
}

Comment: To me it looks like the output si correct based on what is written in the MDN article you linked. In the Syntax -> Return value subtitle, it is said that: "if a handler function: returns a value, the promise returned by 'then' gets resolved with the returned value as its value". That means that when you return the value "B", the promise returned by the handler function get resolved with that value, and it is printed in the console.log

Comment: return v; // you will get your expected result.

Answer (score 3):

When you return a Promise, you don't actually return what's *inside* the Promise but the Promise itself. When you say

```
function api1 () {
 return fetch1().then(v =>{
  console.log("Api1", v);
  return "B"
 );
}
```

you're saying "`console.log` the result of the previous Promise, then return a *new* promise containing `B`.

So when you call

```
api1().then(v => console.log("Api2 call", v));
```

the original Promise (containing "A") has already been consumed and your new Promise contains the string "B" you returned earlier.

To get the output you intended, rewrite your second section like this:

```
function api1 () {
 return fetch1().then(v =>{
  console.log("Api1", v);
  return v;
 );
}
```

Comment: Yes, as I comment to his question, he must return 'v' what he expects.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see I am returning the same value which is returned from fetch1

That's actually not quite true, you're calling `then` after `fetch1`. That does make a difference.

With synchronous, non-promise code is pretty much the same. If you return in a method:

`return sum(3,7).multiply(2);`

You're not just returning `sum(3,7)`, because after it you're calling `multiply(2)`. That will return the number 20, because of the `multiply` call.

With promises it's pretty much the same, like:

```
const myResultPromise = return sumPromise(3,7).then(sumValue => {
  return multiplyPromise(2);
})
```

Here, `myResultPromise` will be a Promise of 20, because `then` attaches a new Promise to the original `sumPromise`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function fetch1 () {
 return new Promise((res, rej) => {
  res("A");
 });
}

function api1 () {
 return fetch1().then(v =>{
  console.log("Api1", v);
  return "B"
 });
}

api1().then(v => console.log("Api2 call", v));
```

When calling `api1().then(v => console.log("Api2 call", v));`, `api1()` will awaiting the resolved promise in the fetch1 to be resolved, which means the `v` in `then` in `api1` function will equal to 'A', then the `then` function will return 'B' to the next then which is the `then` in `then(v => console.log("Api2 call", v));` the value `v` will equal to 'B'. I hope you understand!